# Why does action="localhost" lead to form not doing anything when submitted?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<form id = "myForm" action="localhost" method="get">
    <input name="liftString" type="text">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

This form doesn't do anything when clicking the submit button. I'm not redirected to `localhost`.

If I change the `action` attribute to `"/localhost"` it tries to take me to `file:///localhost?liftString=d` when running the form locally.

If I change `action` to `"http://localhost"`, it correctly takes me to `http://localhost/?liftString=f`.

What is happening in the form example posted? Why does the form do nothing when I click submit?

CLARIFICATION: I understand what's going on when `action="/localhost"` and `action="https://localhost"`. What I don't understand is why NOTHING happens when I have `action="localhost"`.

Comment: Since /localhost takes it to file location I assume it’s being run from the file system and not via a server

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A URL that doesn't start with a scheme (such as `http://`) or the scheme-relative indicator (`//`) is relative to the current URL (unless overridden with `<base>`.

So the browser takes the URL of the current page, strips off everything after the last `/` in it, appends the relative URL (`localhost`) then adds a query string after that.

Since you are using a `file://` scheme to view the page, the form would submit to a file on your computer with no HTTP server to process the form data. Since the file `localhost` doesn't exist, the browser just ignores the form submission request instead.